# How could an evil king start by himself his kingdom from ground-up using his recently conquered kingdom?

Tags: magic, government, super-powers, power-sources

This evil king has a supernatural/magical power, which gives him a big advantage over his enemies and allows him to win battles by himself. Although he has never been a king, he now wants to be one, and for that, he defeated a kingdom and took the throne.

He kidnapped to his kingdom a certain elder known by him who has a great knowledge in the world's natural magical energy source, which could be used for technological development.

Now, how could this kingdom grow and develop, i.e. to have soldiers, right hands, followers, considering that every defensive force was killed? Workers and population could be gotten by enslaving people from other conquered kingdoms/villages, but for that he would need soldiers, because it wouldn't be possible to one single person to enslave a whole people (people are slippery). But how?

P.S.: He is evil, but he can pretend not to be so when needed.

**Edit:**
I had an idea. Instead of him invading the kingdom and killing everyone, maybe he could get in there, kill the guards blocking his passage, go to the throne room and kill the king, announce himself as the new king, create some kind of agreement with the people and the other authorities, and kill every resistance against him. Would it make sense?

Comment: I hope you are setting up this evil king as the antagonist of your story's hero. Because evil superman overlord is boring unless he falls.

Comment: @Mindwin Yeah, he is the villain of the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Baldur's Gate TOB, the Bhaal spawn Yaga-Shura kept his heart bathed in magical flame which granted him immense regenerative powers, and kept it hidden away in a remote mountain fortress protected by fanatical supporters who worshipped him as a God.

Didn't do him much good against the other Bhaal spawn, but it's a good start for your evil anti-hero.

Powerful men attract their own posse, those who want the falling crumbs, those who crave proximity to raw power. He would have zero difficulty building a power base and an army of loyal, worshipful followers if he is indeed near-invincible. Power attracts power. Soon, powerful lords would sooner bow their heads than face him in battle. He wouldn't even have to fight anymore, except very rarely.

Answer (score 2):

Evil kings/leaders often rise to power by pretending to be good (or worse still, believing themselves to be good) and better than the current king. You could have it that the previous king was corrupt and enslaved / stole from the populace with his evil army and along came this king with his Superman-like power and went from region to region destroying the existing soldiers and saving everyone, thereby building up a loyal following from grateful newly-freed slaves.

Even the most powerful magical king would need a large support because even if he can defeat armies by himself, he can't quell unrest, collect taxes and enforce his will throughout his realm. Not to mention do all the stuff a king is supposed to do (build the roads, schools, hospitals, sewers, aquaducts, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be not to have depopulated the kingdom to begin with.

But assuming he's starting with a barren wasteland and only a few supporters, the magician and the kidnappers, the obvious course of action would be to force 
the magician create some kind of spell of attraction to bring people to his kingdom.

The point would be to create a situation were people could "check out but never leave"

For example, what if he used the magician's power to create a utopia (huge houses, natural beauty, etc) where everyone in the surrounding area wanted to go but once they went there they would not be able to leave again without being branded traitors.

Since he doesn't need an army he could instead create a clerical cast or bureaucracy from the most loyal subjects and use them to bend the people trapped in the kingdom to his will. Of course anyone who saw through the farce would find themselves in his dungeon after being informed on by the others. Think 1984 medieval style.

Comment: Plenty of room at the Kingdom California....

Answer (score 1):

If He has money he could hire soldiers, paid mercenaries could serve as his fight force alternatively he could use prisoners. Prisoners would be particular loyal subject, but as long as you make sure that all the deserters are killed and they will be loyal enough. There is another way, through out history governments that didn't trust there people used slave soldiers. This has proven to work if the slaves have been take as children. Of course this could be a problem if you need a the army right away.